# Functional vs imperative (statements): writing this in the most compact way

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, use-state, imperative-programming

Looking for the shortest, most elegant wat to write this. I really like option 2. However, i get this error:

`Argument of type 'boolean[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<ISlugSegment[]>`

Which makes sense cause in #2 I am returning endpoint.autoGenerate, which is a boolean.

So, asking for some guidance here on how to re-rewrite #1 in the shortest way.

This is React by the way. Using the useState hook.

```
let [_endpoints, _setEndpoints] = useState(params.endpoints);

// 1. verbose (imperative?)
    const copiedEndpoints = _endpoints.map((endpoint: ISlugSegment) => {
      endpoint.autoGenerate = (endpoint.localeKey === _selectedLocale) ? endpoint.autoGenerate = false : endpoint.autoGenerate;
      return endpoint;
    });
_setEndpoints(copiedEndpoints);
// end

// 2. short: 1 line (functional?)
    _setEndpoints(_endpoints.map((endpoint: ISlugSegment) => (endpoint.localeKey === _selectedLocale) ? endpoint.autoGenerate = false : endpoint.autoGenerate));
// end
```

#2 results in an array of Booleans instead of an Array with ISlugSegments Objects. And what I need is the latter.

Comment: Do you even have to `_setEndpoints` when you mutate some `endpoint`s, but keep the same objects?

Comment: Yes, endpoints is existent: an Array filled with Objects of type ISlugSegments.

Comment: No doubt, but you initialize your `_endpoints`state already with `useState` to the array `params.endpoints`. In fact, as updating state triggers a re-rendering, doing so in _every_ render cycle should create an infinite loop, no?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the second approach if you satisfy Typescript by explicitly stating the types to `useState`

```js
let [_endpoints, _setEndpoints] = useState<Array<ISlugSegment|boolean>>(params.endpoints)
```

Comment: This won't behave in the same way as "option" #1.

Comment: Exact @manfred. I get type assertion, but it is not want it to be.